# Checking for protocol availability in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, preprocessor, protocols, watchconnectivity

I am adopting WatchConnectivity, but I am still supporting iOS7 and iOS 8 for which this library is not available. Moreover I am adopting protocol WCSessionDelegate also not supported but this older systems.
In ObjectiveC I would have used preprocessing directives to shield this declaration and the protocol adoption from versions not supporting them. How do I handle that in Swift so that the app does not crash on older systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thank @joern for the suggestion of adopting the protocol in a delegate which I here summarize:

```
@available(iOS 9, *)
extension inArrivoHDAppDelegate: WCSessionDelegate {}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID283

> You can use the `is` and `as` operators described in Type Casting to check
>   for protocol conformance, and to cast to a specific protocol. Checking
>   for and casting to a protocol follows exactly the same syntax as
>   checking for and casting to a type:
>
> The `is` operator returns true if an instance conforms to a protocol and returns false if it does not.
>
> The `as?` version of the downcast operator
>   returns an optional value of the protocol’s type, and this value is
>   nil if the instance does not conform to that protocol.
>
> The `as!` version
>   of the downcast operator forces the downcast to the protocol type and
>   triggers a runtime error if the downcast does not succeed.

```
for object in objects {
    if let objectWithArea = object as? HasArea {
        print("Area is \(objectWithArea.area)")
    } else {
        print("Something that doesn't have an area")
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, but that may be just used at runtime. Include and protocol conformance may only be shielded at compile time, though, where of course 'is' and 'as' are not available, nor any of the common tools to check the version.

Comment: You are building code agains latest iOS SDK, so your app is know the interface. But checking is performed at runtime. Or do you think that in case of Objective-C Xcode compiles code for every iOS SDK? It even doesn't ship them!

Comment: I am afraid I did not understand you.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2 you can now use Availability Checking to shield features from older system versions where they are not available.

You can use the availability check in a `if`, `guard`, `while` statement if you want to shield only part of a method, or you can shield whole functions, extensions or even classes.

Here's an example on how to shield `WCSession` and `WCSessionDelegate` from versions lower than iOS9:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            if WCSession.isSupported() {
                let session = WCSession.defaultSession()
                session.delegate = self
                session.activateSession()
            }
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 9, *)
extension ViewController: WCSessionDelegate {
    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That I also did, of course, Yet the issue is again in the include directives and protocol adoption where the #available tag may not be used. Of course I am not sure whether that would be an issue in iOS 7, as I no longer have iOS 7 devices to use for a test.

Comment: Can you add an code  example for an include directive and protocol adoption from your code to your question? I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: In my answer I am shielding the protocol adoption from older system versions by using an extension.

Comment: What do you mean, are you emulating WatchConnectivity in the extension?

Comment: No, I am just making sure that the code that needs iOS9 (WatchConnectivity) is hidden from older systems so that the app does not crash. Thats why I moved the protocol adoption to an extension to be able to use the availability API.

Comment: And what is the syntax you used for that in order to not porting the problem to the extension?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93237/discussion-between-joern-and-fabrizio-bartolomucci).

Comment: How to do it with Objective C? As I am integrating ARkit I am getting warning from xcode for its delegate method.

Comment: @TheiCoder Can you please add a new question for that and show your code?