# Swift: how to check for availability of protocols?

Tags: swift, ios9, availability

Since Swift 2, there is a cleaner way to check if some class or property is available:

```
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
var someVarHere = someClassHere()
```

however, I can't find anywhere how to check for protocol availability, e.g. `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate`. Any suggestions?

Comment: kind of duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308196/checking-for-protocol-availability-in-swift

Comment: Actually it IS duplicate :) So, I will answer my question to prevent downvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @lu_, I got a solution: Using extensions.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            let sfc = SFSafariViewController(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.bg")!)
            sfc.delegate = self
            presentViewController(sfc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 9, *)
extension ViewController: SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    func safariViewControllerDidFinish(controller: SFSafariViewController) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```